# Can you union without overriding in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming I have the following tables:

```
Name | Occupation
A
B
C
D
E
Workplace | Phone Number
A
B
C
```

I want to perform a select to merge the tables into a single table:

```
MyName | Type
A | Person
B | Person
C | Person
D | Person
E | Person
A | Workplace
B | Workplace
C | Workplace
```

How do I accomplish this? I tried:

```
SET @a = 'Person'
SET @b = 'Name'
SELECT Name, @a FROM tablea
UNION
SELECT Workplace, @b FROM tableb
```

And the output appears to be all "Person" in the second column and there are no "Workplace". What am I doing wrong?

Or is there someway I could do something like get the following from a single SELECT statement:

```
MyName
A_Person 
B_Person 
C_Person 
D_Person 
E_Person 
A_Workplace
B_Workplace
C_Workplace
```

Note: I am using MySQL Workbench

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf8746/5 Please show the exact code you are using.

Comment: Just a slight modification to your query and you've got the output you wanted: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf8746/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to accept your query, but it did accept this:

```
SELECT Name, 'Person' FROM tablea
UNION
SELECT Workplace, 'Workplace' FROM tableb
```

Comment: I think you just need semicolons after setting the variables. See my fiddle in comment to OP.

Comment: @bernie Oops, my screen wasn't big enough to show that there was more than one "result" and I didn't think to scroll down...

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`:

```
SELECT Name, @a FROM tablea
UNION ALL
SELECT Workplace, @b FROM tableb
```

UNION removes duplicate (and in most databases sorts the results too).

UNION ALL keeps all rows in the order selected.

Comment: If there are different data in the 2nd column the rows wouldn't be duplicates.